# Position divs based on numeric class name

Tags: javascript, php, css, position

I have a series of events that I need to plot vertically down the page in relation to the date in the class (YYYY-MM-DD).

```
<div class="event 1990-03-18"></div>
<div class="event 2015-10-30"></div>
<div class="event 2016-08-03"></div>
<div class="event 2017-05-20"></div>
<div class="event 2017-05-24"></div>
```

The earliest date in the would be positioned absolutely from the top of the page. The next sequential dates would appear below the earliest one but in correlation to the time difference. So there would be a larger distance between these events: 1990-03-18 and 2015-10-30. And a smaller distance between 2017-05-20 and 2017-05-24.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? Please show us how you have approached the problem and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Are you generating these divs with PHP from data containing those dates? If so, can you include that code?

Comment: This is nothing I would solve with classes. I would rather calculate the relative or absolute position in php and set it in `@style`. But please, show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible JavaScript solution https://jsfiddle.net/stzanr1s/4/

html imporved by wrapper with `height` and `position:relative`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="event 1990-03-18"></div>
  <div class="event 2008-10-30"></div>
  <div class="event 2016-08-03"></div>
  <div class="event 2017-05-20"></div>
  <div class="event 2017-05-24"></div>
</div>
```

and script which find min, max and count relative positions of all items.

```
maxDate = new Date(0);
minDate = new Date(0);
var events = document.querySelectorAll(".event");

function getDate(event) {
    var clases = event.className.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < clases.length; i++) {
    if (clases[i] != "event") {
        return new Date(Date.parse(clases[i]));
    }
}

function findMinMax() {
    minDate = getDate(events[0]);
    maxDate = getDate(events[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {
        var d = getDate(events[i]);
        if (d.getTime() < minDate.getTime()) {
            minDate = d;
        }
        if (d.getTime() > maxDate.getTime()) {
            maxDate = d;
        }
    }
}

function setPositions() {
    findMinMax();
    var range = maxDate.getTime() - minDate.getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var d = getDate(events[i]);
        events[i].style.top = + ((d.getTime() - minDate.getTime()) * 100 / range) + "%";
    }
}

setPositions();
```

fiddle contains some style which visualize events by red lines.